# HTTP hole punching - Web server behind NAT

Tags: https, nat, hole-punching

I have some Raspberry Pi servers behind NATs (non configurable, ISP provided), on dynamic IPs, and a "master" server with static IP and port forwarding configured on the router. I want to be able to access the page served by any of those RPi servers from any browser. I've read about TCP hole punching, but I can't figure out how to make it work from a browser (I guess using AJAX). I could use the "master" server as a relay server, but don't know how to. BTW, all traffic to/from the servers use HTTPS, not HTTP.

EDIT:
The Raspberries and the server are NOT on the same network.

Comment: You can use some thing like https://github.com/fatedier/frp to expose ur rpi to internet from behind NAT

Answer (score -3):

You might investigate the use of a reverse proxy (I've used NGINX).  A reverse proxy allows traffic to hit your server with the static IP, and forward HTTP traffic to other servers behind the firewall.

It gets a little more tricky with HTTPS, but it can be worked out.  You'll have to forward port 443 or 80 from your router to the server with the reverse proxy.

Comment: According to Apache's documentation, reverse proxying needs static IPs for the other servers (in this case both the IP and the number of RPi servers are dynamic), and its not able to traverse a NAT.

Comment: @ChristianRodriguez Internal addresses can be static.  Missing your point.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to this. I'm trying to solve this using a different approach, and I asked a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879303/ssh-reverse-tunnel-not-working-for-webserver).

Comment: Reverse proxy is NOT a solution AT ALL. @Xavier J is wasting your time here.
To work, the reverse proxy has to be behind your ISP's NAT because it needs to access each RPi directly (if not behind the NAT, the reverse proxy will suffers from the same problem as your client; it can't connect to the RPis because of the NAT). And so when you place the reverse proxy behind the NAT (if you can in the first place), how does the client reach it? A reverse proxy is not magical, it's jut another hop in the network path.