# SSH reverse tunnel not working for webserver

Tags: ssh, https, ssh-tunnel

I have a webapp running on a Raspberry Pi, which is behind a NAT, and I'm trying to make a tunnel to the company's server so that I can access it from the web. Right now I've been able to establish a tunnel using `ssh -fN -R 192.168.0.28:54321:localhost:443 username@192.168.0.28` (both the server and the RPi are in the same LAN at the time), and doing `curl -k https://192.168.0.28:54321` returns the contents of the webpage hosted in the RPi, but only if I do it from the server. I have set `GatewayPorts yes` and `AllowTcpForwarding yes` (which anyway is the default).

Comment: "but only if I do it from the server" What exactly happens if you try it from something other than the server? What specific command do you run, and what error messages or other behavior do you get?

Comment: @Kenster If I try to access from a browser, it times-out (`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`). If I do it from curl (`curl -k https://192.168.0.28:54321`) it does nothing, not even returns an error... not even returns! The command line just keeps busy.

Comment: @Kenster Ok, it just took a ridiculous amount of time, but curl times out as well (gives errno 7 - Connect failed)

Comment: Did you try the same when they were on different networks ? And did it work then ?

Comment: Any idea on how to do hole punching without opening a dedicated tunnel ? I have to support thousands of devices on a single server and blocking a dedicated port for each device is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the firewall on the server blocking the port. ¬¬

To open said port, the command is `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 54321 -j ACCEPT`, which says that any connection comming to the TCP port 54321 must be accepted.